# Php array: Spot the difference!

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I can't figure out what the difference is between the final result of `$arrayParams` in this snippet of PHP.

The function takes string `$types`, and another parameter called `$params`. `$params` itself can be a single value of any type, or an array of values of any type.

The purpose of this code is for binding to `call_user_func_array()` later on in the code.

The final `$arrayParams` variable needs to be an array with index 0 as the original `$types` string, and then the following indices are to be references of the string(s) passed in as `$params`.

```
if(is_array($params)) {
  // Make a new array, first index is $types string.
  $arrayParams = array($types);

  // Loop over $params array and add the pointer of each index to $arrayParams.
  // ??? This doesn't seem to be working ???
  foreach($params as $p) {
    $arrayParams[] = &$p;
  }
 }
else {
  // This works fine here, very simple.
  $arrayParams = array($types, &$params);
}
```

The `var_dump` of `$array_params`, when passing `$params` as an array shows all keys after the first to be a pointer to the same value (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ...
foreach($params as &$p) {
    $arrayParams[] = &$p;
}
unset($p);
// ...
```

`foreach` operates on a copy of the `$params`-array, unless you specify to use references on the iteration.

Comment: Can I ask why $p needs to be unset?

Comment: @Greg See [the warning here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Accepted answer because of `unset` tip. Thanks :)